# Can rapids kneighborsclassifiers and kneighborsregressor be run with rapids?

Tags: knn, rapids

I want to run kneighborregressor and kneighborclassifier on GPU. However, I cannot find out them in RAPIDS. Are these functions currently implemented or planned to be developed?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying code is there for KNN in RAPIDS 0.10, but it does not yet have the Regressor and Classifier interfaces. You can use cuml KNN to find the nearest neighbors themselves, though. In 0.11, we will support these interfaces like in sklearn.